# Pandas: use apply to split column into 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column ('location') that has information about the city and state separated by a comma. Some values are None.

I wrote a function to split the data into city and state and clean it up a little:

```
def split_data(x):
    if x:
        s = x.split(',')
        city = s[0].lstrip().rstrip()
        state = s[1].lstrip().rstrip()
    else:
        city = None
        state = None
    return city, state
```

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to create 2 separate columns from this function. 
If I use the following:

```
df['location_info'] = df['location'].apply(split_data)
```

It creates a tuple into the 'location_info' column.

What is the best way to create 2 new columns in the dataframe - one called 'city' and the other called 'state'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use vectorized functions [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df[['city','state']]=df['location'].str.split(',',expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Or:

```
df[['city','state']] = df['location'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df['city'] = df['city'].str.strip()
df['state'] = df['state'].str.strip()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location':[' a,h ',' t ,u', None]})
print (df)
  location
0     a,h 
1     t ,u
2     None

df[['city','state']]=df['location'].str.split(',',expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
print (df)
  location  city state
0     a,h      a     h
1     t ,u     t     u
2     None  None  None
```

But if need really use your function (e.g. is more complicated) add `Series`:

```
def split_data(x):
    if x:
        s = x.split(',')
        city = s[0].strip()
        state = s[1].strip()
    else:
        city = None
        state = None
    return pd.Series([city, state], index=['city','state'])

df[['city','state']] = df['location'].apply(split_data)
print (df)
  location  city state
0     a,h      a     h
1     t ,u     t     u
2     None  None  None
```

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately, I simplified the function for this example and now I can't extrapolate your answer to my real problem. Sorry. I actually have another split that I'm using (the location format is: high school in city, state) and I just need the city and state so I'm using an additional split(' in '). Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then use your function with `return pd.Series([city, state], index=['city','state'])`.